# what is the procedure followed to divide the background into squares like facebook supercity, farmvillie

Tags: apache-flex, facebook

I have planned to develop a game in flex  in which the users will build buildings on a plain surface. I want to divide those lands into pieces and allow the user to build the buildings on the pieces of the surface. How do i divide the land into pieces. I have seen face book application supercity, farm vilie etc. I want to develop same as that. What is the method followed to develop the squares in the background.

See this link background rendering done in Maya

http://www.3dtutorialzone.com/tutorial?id=88

how to do this using flex

Answer (score 0):

You should read up about:

[Isometric Projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection)

and

[Tile-Based Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile-based_video_game)